# Implementing heapsort without using a separate Heap Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, implementation, heapsort

I want to implement heapsort without the use of the heap data structure. More precisely I want all the changes to be done on the original array. I tried to implement it, but I got stuck because it turns in another algorithm for example selection sort or a bubble sort. So what sort would be called a heapsort provided that we don't use the heap data structure?

Comment: In-place has been pretty much standard for [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). Once comfortable with your implementation, try to understand [smoothsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort).

Comment: (You might want to change the title in direction of …`without using a separate Heap Data Structure`)

Comment: mhm thanks for the correction and for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The exciting thing about a heap is that it can be realized simply as an arrangement of items in an array -- it does not require any separate data structure with pointers among the elements.  Greybeard points you to the wikipedia page, which has a very good treatment of this, but in a nutshell the idea is to build the heap in place by swapping elements, and then sort, again by swapping elements in the same array.